# NAT iptables : why wrong/empty destination in saved config?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables, nat

Here is rules I put in iptables :

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING 
                -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 19.11.11.1:80
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But when I (terminal) list them, I get **destination 0.0.0.0/0 instead of 19.11.11.1**
Exactly :

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 210 packets, 43762 bytes)
pkts bytes target prot opt in source destination 
0   0    DNAT tcp -- wlan0 * 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
    tcp dpt:80 to:19.11.11.1:80
```

**Where am I wrong ? Thank you.**

*Nota Bene : Traffic comes from 19.11.11.0/24 subnet to 19.11.11.1:80.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks right to me - maybe you are reading the output wrong.

The source and destination (in the packet) TO MATCH is  0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 - ie anything, which is consistent with the rule you wrote (you did not specify a source or destination).

The action to take on that packet is to redirect "to:19.11.11.1:80" - ie the text on the following line.

Answer (score 2):

The `destination` column lists the destination IP address of the original packet (before NAT) as specified by the `-d` or `--destination` parameter. Since you did not specify a destination parameter, the entry matches all TCP packets destined to port 80 on any destination IP address.